# How to have a function continue even if its parameters are not defined

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am making a game where there are choices that the user can pick, I want to create a function to print the question for me easily, but not every question will have 5 answers. How can I make it so it will only print the ones that have a parameter. I tried what is below but it does not work.

```
def sceneQuestion(question, Aone, Atwo, Athree, Afour, Afive):
    print(question)
    global choice
    choice="?"
    print(' ')
    print("  <a> "+Aone)
    print("  <b> "+Atwo)
    try:
      Athree
    except NameError:
      print(' ')
    else:
      print (' <c> '+Athree)
    try:
      Afour
    except NameError:
     print(' ')
    else:
      print (' <d> '+Afour)
    try:
     Afive
    except NameError:
     print(' ')
    else:
     print (' <e> '+Afive)
sceneQuestion('What do you want to do?', 'Eat food', 'Save George', 'Call George an idiot')
```

How would I do this, Thanks.

Please comment if you have any questions

Comment: Give a default value to the parameters - perhaps a None value. Rather than try-except, use if-else to see the value of parameter and go accordingly.

Comment: Don't confuse _"Not defined"_ and _"defined to be the value `None`"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here's how you'd do it if the problem weren't better suited to passing `*args`, as in Adam's answer:

```
def sceneQuestion(question, Aone, Atwo, Athree=None, Afour=None, Afive=None):
    print(question)
    global choice
    choice="?"
    print(' ')
    print("  <a> "+Aone)
    print("  <b> "+Atwo)
    if Athree is not None: print (' <c> '+Athree)
    if Afour is not None:  print (' <d> '+Afour)
    if Afive is not None:  print (' <e> '+Afive)
```

Default argument values can be set in the function signature, and then the `None` values checked for in your code

Answer (score 3):

This is when you'd use optional arguments. In this case it should be a series of arguments.

```
def question(question, *answers):
    # answers is now a list of everything passed
    # to the function OTHER than the first argument
    print(question)
    for lett, ans in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, answers):
        print("  <{L}>  {ans}".format(L=lett, ans=ans))
```